# I get an "uncaught reference error" and need help please

Tags: jquery

I am learning to code from codecademy.com and one of the jquery lessons did not work properly. I copied it to my webhost to see if I could get it to work there or use the javascript console to figure out the problem but I am stuck.

Here is the script.js page:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    $('div').mouseover(function() {
        $('div').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
   $('div').mouseout(function() {
        $('div').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    });
});
```

`

The second line is the error message I am receiving and I can't figure out why. I am using Chromium on Ubuntu if that matters (from the different things I've seen in trying to figure this out, it appears that it does matter for some reason).

If anyone can help me explain this, I would appreciate it.

If you want to see the original page it is at learningtocode.nileriverfoods.com.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Do you have included jquery?

Comment: Note that `$('document')` should be `$(document)`. The first one is referencing a tag named document, the second references the document object which, as there is no document tag, is probably what you want.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 jQuery understands `$('document')` as a synonym for `$(document)` (although AFAIK it's an undocumented feature that shouldn't really be used).

Comment: @Juhana I know it works but it is very wrong and that bothers me. :P

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in your page. You need to either download this file http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js or just reference it.

Comment: First, I thought that (document) was right but when I got the error message I tried to throw in the quotes to see if that would work. It didn't give me an additional error so I guess I forgot to take them back out.

Second, how do I "reference" jQuery?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" />`

Comment: Do I just add that line to my script.js file? or to my default.html file?

Comment: Ok, I just copied and pasted all the code to my script.js file and now it works - sort of. I'll figure out the rest on my own. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add that to the head section of your HTML file above the other script tags.